# Custom helper - dependencies link_to remote

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, twitter-bootstrap, dependencies, helper

I'm currently writing a custom form helper based on bootstrap and I have problem with dependencies (I think):

```
class BootstrapFormBuilder < ActionView::Helpers::FormBuilder
  include ActionView::Helpers::UrlHelper
  include ActionView::Helpers::OutputSafetyHelper

  alias :super_collection_select :collection_select

  def collection_select_append(method, collection, value_method, text_method, options = {}, html_options = {})
    ('<div class="control-group' + has_error(object.errors[method]) + '">' +
      label(method, :class => "control-label") +
      '<div class="controls">' +
        '<div class="input-append">' +
          super_collection_select(method, collection, value_method, text_method, objectify_options(options), @default_options.merge(html_options)) +
          '<span class="add-on">' +
            link_to(raw("<i class\"icon-white icon-ok\"></i>"), {:controller => "myController", :action => "myAction"}, :method => "post", :remote => true, :html => { :val1 => "val1", :val2 => "val2" } ) +
          '</span>' +
        '</div>' +
        get_error_message(object.errors[method]) +
      '</div>' +
    '</div>').html_safe
  end

end
```

This is returning an error:

```
undefined local variable or method `controller' for #<..>
```

Comment: please specify the line number of error and file name

Comment: The error is on the link_to line in my helper file. I think is on the url:
link_to raw("..."), **{:controller => "myController", :action => "myAction"}**, :method => "post", :remote => true, :html => { ... }

Missing includes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that you missed the `:url` option for controller in this:

```
link_to(raw("<i class\"icon-white icon-ok\"></i>"), {:controller => "myController", :action => "myAction"}, :method => "post", :remote => true, :html => { :val1 => "val1", :val2 => "val2" } )
```

TRY:

```
class BootstrapFormBuilder < ActionView::Helpers::FormBuilder
  include ActionView::Helpers::UrlHelper
  include ActionView::Helpers::OutputSafetyHelper

  alias :super_collection_select :collection_select

  def collection_select_append(method, collection, value_method, text_method, options = {}, html_options = {})
    ('<div class="control-group' + has_error(object.errors[method]) + '">' +
      label(method, :class => "control-label") +
      '<div class="controls">' +
        '<div class="input-append">' +
          super_collection_select(method, collection, value_method, text_method, objectify_options(options), @default_options.merge(html_options)) +
          '<span class="add-on">' +
            link_to(raw("<i class\"icon-white icon-ok\"></i>"), :url => {:controller => "myController", :action => "myAction"}, :method => "post", :remote => true, :html => { :val1 => "val1", :val2 => "val2" } ) +
          '</span>' +
        '</div>' +
        get_error_message(object.errors[method]) +
      '</div>' +
    '</div>').html_safe
  end

end
```

Comment: Thanks to reply. But in [the API doc](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper/link_to) is not obligatory if using extra literal hash. But i've tested and nothing changed.

Comment: I think you are posting with a :as option so you need `:url` or else helpers need that to work than controllers..See last line of your link.

Comment: I've tested to use the name of the route like `link_to raw("..."), my_route_name_path, ...`. It's return undefined variable or method  'my_route_name_path'. Same with an alias (:as). Missing include?

Comment: this is because there is no route with the name `my_route_name_path`. You should try to run `rake routes` to determine what are the valid routes you have and then put in link_to.

Comment: The name of the route is correct. Actually this is work with charme by jQuery. But I'll replace my event handler attachment (.on()) by link_to remote...